# Golang: Gorilla websocket, состояние подключения

Tags: golang, websocket

Есть такая функция

```
func WsHandler_remote_1(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    quit := make(chan int)
    conn, err := wsupgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    go db.CreateChanelNotify(conn, 1, quit)
    defer conn.Close()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to set websocket upgrade: %+v", err)
        return
    }
    for {
        t, msg, err := conn.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("!!")
            break
        }

        conn.WriteMessage(t, msg)
    }
}
```

Как определить что соединение закрылось (при обрыве связи, или если клиент закрыл браузер)

Comment: Попробуйте https://stackoverflow.com/a/36096126/678491

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно проверить, является ли тип возвращаемой ошибки `*websocket.CloseError`:

```
t, msg, err := conn.ReadMessage()
if err != nil {
    if err, ok := err.(*websocket.CloseError); ok {
        log.Printf("connection closed, code: %d, text: %q", err.Code, err.Text)
        break
    }
    break
}
```

Подробнее:

- http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/websocket#CloseError
- http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/websocket#constants

Comment: Сколько раз читал доку, так и не видел этого, спасибо.